# React Alternative for window.history.pushState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am using `router-dom v5.2.0` I came across a use-case where I want to add some query params to the existing URL and did not want to re render the whole component.

**Example**

1. If I go with traditional `history.push()` I have a Modal of Filters and clicking on a filter updates the query param which in turn re-renders the component and the modal closes

**Why window.histoy.pushState ?**

1. It allows me to update the URL query params without re-rendering the whole component

`i.e It does not close the modal.`

**Problem with window.history.pushState**

1. I can't use `useEffect` or any other method to watch changes made to the URL and call API's accordingly

Comment: Have you tried `useLocation` with `useParams` ?

Comment: @ImanpalSingh That is not applicable since I am storing `query parameters` and want the component to render regardless if my parameter is empty or filled